# Android AchartEngine: Panning and Click listener

Tags: android, charts

My question is simple. But I am not getting. When panning then it also called the mChartView's OnClickListener. But I want when tap on graph then and then call OnClickListener 
and when panning, disable the click.

Comment: Are you still looking for the solution on this one?

Comment: No, I am done with this.

Comment: Maybe it would help posting the answer so that others benefit from it?

Answer (score 3):

I am giving my own question's answer. Just add the pan Listener to check the panning is continue or not. For that set a boolean and check condition in OnClickListener.

```
mChartView.addPanListener(new PanListener() {
                @Override
                public void panApplied() {
                    isPanEnables = true;

                }
            });
```

Comment: When and where do you set isPanEnabled to false?

Comment: On chartview's click listener

Comment: for the new in android, `panApplied()` is called several time and end with a single `onClick`